# Better approach to return HttpStatus code Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception, status

I develope rest service using spring for a long time, and till now my approach to return http status code was like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sth")
    public void name(HttpServletResponse response){
        boolean lever = service.doSomethingAndReturnTrueIfSucceedOrFalseIfNot();
        if(lever){
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }else{
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST); //NOT_FOUND or whatever
        }
    }
```

But I am sure there is a better way to do this. I know that we have **@ResponseStatus** annotation, but it is.. static, I mean it returns always **the same code** - but what if something would have gone wrong? Then I dont want for example, to have 200 OK as response code.

I found the solution like this: add **@ResponseStatus** as static response code, but when something goes wrong in the controller, then **throw some custom exception** and catch it in new **@ControllerAdvice class**, and there also add @ResponseStatus annotation and return proper code.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sth")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void name(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
        boolean lever = service.doSomethingAndReturnTrueIfSucceedOrFalseIfNot();
        if(!lever){
            throw new SomethingWentWrongCustomException("Not okay..");
        }
    }
```

And then catch it in the class like:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SomethingControllerAdvice{
    @ExceptionHandler(value = SomethingWentWrongCustomException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public void someName(){
    }
}
```

It seems to be quite elegant solution, but the code is quite.. wordy, isnt it?
On the other hand, If I adopt this for whole application and create @ControllerAdvice classes, then It could have sense
What do you think about it? Is there any other, maybe better approach?

I hope it is not opinion based question and I dont want it to be. I just dont want to use anti-patterns and have good practices from begginings :)

Comment: Return a `ResponseEntity` instead of setting the response.

Comment: Is it good, when I return ResponseEntity in pure RESTful service?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? That is the whole point of the thing...

Comment: then, the ResponseEntity class would have to be created and processed in @Service layer and just returned to the controller, am I right? And is it possible to avoid "if" like the one upper? because I would still have to check "if everything is okay" condition

Comment: No.... You create it based on the result in the controller. The `ResponseEntity` is a web class you don't want that stuff in your service layer. You still have to check somewhere although you could make it a shorthand if.

Comment: and what about using @ControlerAdivce as I said in the post?

Comment: Using exceptions for control flow is a no-go imho. Exceptions are for exceptional situations... So no in my book that isn't an option.

Comment: i suppose so as well, but I was given that advice :) so I will check whats most appropriate approach for my particular case and use it, thanks! helped me a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Returning `ResponseEntity` as @M-deinum wrote is definitely way to go. Additionally, instead of defining behavior for each exception in `@ControllerAdvice` you can just annotate your exceptions classes with appropriate `@ResponseStatus` annotations.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
class SomeException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

Comment: so then, there is no way to avoid using 'if' statement in any form? and what about @ControllerAdvice and catching properly exceptions? too wordy as I have thought?

Comment: Avoid `if` by not-returning boolean from your method. I believe void and doing nothing if succeed and throwing exception when failed would be appropriate in most cases, but of course your use case may be different.